# What is wrong with Double Tenacity?

Tags: league-of-legends

I watched Krepo's stream and he said, "That guy has double tenacity. He doesn't jungle."

And I saw some threads bashing people with double tenacity.

**Can someone tell me why you shouldn't build double tenacity?**

Comment: By double tenacity do you mean having two items with tenacity on it?

Comment: Tenacity sources are all unique as far as I'm aware (with the exception of Irelia's passive, which I don't believe includes the word tenacity).  So they don't stack - building multiple tenacity items is a hugely inefficient use of gold.

Comment: @KAI as well as Zac's ultimate, and Mundo's W, but an exhaustive list isn't necessary. Basically, *innate* champion tenacity stacks with item tenacity, but item tenacity doesn't stack with the tenacity from other items.

Comment: @SadlyNot Basically yes - my understanding is that innate abilities aren't technically tenacity - they are just some form of crowd control reduction.  Only items technically give tenacity, so tenacity actually never stacks.

Answer (score 5):

Tenacity sources are all unique as far as I'm aware. So they don't stack - building multiple tenacity items is a hugely inefficient use of gold.

Krepo's comment about junglers was probably just noting that the most common way to get double tenacity is Spirit of the Ancient Golem (a jungle item) + Mercury Treads, so junglers are most aware of the fact that double tenacity doesn't work.